# Node JS : Editing .hbs files not reflecting changes in Browser View

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, sequelize.js

I am new to Node and working on an application using NodeJS, Express, MySql and Sequelize. Its an application that performs CRUD operations.
For learning Purpose, I am working in a github project.

I came across **.hbs file** in Views folder.

[image]

I tried to edit the Heading name in this file, but still my changes are not reflecting in Browser View.

[image]

Is there anything I am missing? Even after restarting server, my changes are not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Reason :*

**Handlebars** (hbs) is a server side view template. It needs to be compiled on the server when any changes are made to it. It is **not a .html** for which you don't need to restart the node server to see the changes.

*Solution :*

Restart the node app to reflect any changes or better use [nodemon](http://npmjs.com/package/nodemon).

Cheers.

*P.S : Mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.*

Comment: I tried restarting node app, but still changes are not there. I mentioned it in my question though.

How to use nodemon in my app?

Comment: @AnkitPandey Try enabling `disable cache` under network tab in dev tools.

Comment: @AnkitPandey Try opening it in another browser. Let me know